# Edmonds Karp algorithm and 0 1 capacities

Tags: algorithm, edmonds-karp

What is the Edmonds Karp (BFS) upper bound when the only available capacities are 0 and 1?

*I don't understand the difference when the capacities are only 0 and 1, I know that Ford Fulkerson finds that flow value is 0 or 1, if the capacities are 0 and 1. Does this help me?*

Comment: There is no difference in 0 1 case.

Answer (score 0):

In Edmonds-karp algorithm in each run one of  an edges will be saturated, so there is no difference between 0 1 or random capacity edges. means both running times are same, also algorithm works properly.